# Regex to replace a string in HTML but not within a link or heading

Tags: php, html, regex

I am looking for a regex to replace a given string in a html page but only if the string is not a part of the tag itself or appearing as text inside a link or a heading.

Examples:

Looking for 'replace_me'

`<p>You can replace_me just fine</p>`  OK

`<a href='replace_me'>replace_me</a>`
no match

`<h3>replace_me</h3>`
no match

`<a href='/test/'><span>replace_me</span></a>` no match

`<p style="background:url('replace_me')">replace_me<h1>replace_me</h1></p>` first no match, second OK, third no match

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I have found a working regex

```
\b(replace_me)\b(?!(?:(?!<\/?[ha].*?>).)*<\/[ha].*?>)(?![^<>]*>)
```

Comment: This would be a pain to do in regex, but: (i) what language? (ii) would you consider using an HTML parser instead? Also, I think this may be within realm of XSLT.

Comment: Wouldn't a HTML parser use regex-es too?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It parses the HTML character by character and stores all relevant parts in a tree-like data structure.

Answer (score 0):

[Parsing HTML with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) is a Bad Idea that will drive you insane. Using regex on this is probably not quite as bad, but a few things to think about in whatever approach you take:

1. How many of these are there in a page?
2. How many pages will you be doing this to?
3. Will you be hand-checking the output, or is it automated?
4. Which programming language(s) are you using for this?

I think the best way is not with a "simple" (read: horrendously complicated) regex, but a proper program that has some logic behind it - unless regular expressions are Turing Complete and someone else can provide a regex to do what you want, of course :)

Comment: 1. There can be more then one
2 & 3. Automated
4. PHP

One of the solutions might be to first replace all links and headings between let's say <noreplace> tags, then perform a regex ignoring content inside these tags?

Comment: @Alphax you are just coward. if you dont want to use regex its fine by me but dont expect others to not to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(replace_me)\b(?!(?:(?!<\/?[ha].*?>).)*<\/[ha].*?>)(?![^<>]*>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - given a string of HTML I wanted to replace all instances of the string `tio2` with `TiO<sub>2</sub>`, and `ticl4` with `TiCl<sub>4</sub>`.

This was easy to accomplish with simple string replacement but there are were some instances where the 'needle' strings occur in domain names e.g. `www.ilovetio2.com`, `www.tastytastyticl4.info`.  In these cases the href attributes would be broken by the string replacement.

Rather than mess around trying to find a single, complex regex I opted to make two passes over the HTML string:

- Replace ALL instances with `str_ireplace`
- Find any href attributes containing `<sub>...</sub>` and fix them `preg_replace_callback`

  ```
  public static function subscriptStrings($str)
  {

      // $str is arbitrary string which may be HTML, may be plain text

      // Define search / replacements
      $map = [
          'tio2' => 'TiO<sub>2</sub>',
          'ticl4' => 'TiCl<sub>4</sub>'
      ];

      // Replace ALL instances, paying no heed to their context
      $str = str_ireplace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $str);

      // Make a second pass, specifically looking for href values
      $str = preg_replace_callback('/href="[^"]+"/', function ($str) {

          // Return the href value stripped of <sub> tags
          return str_replace(['<sub>', '</sub>'], '', $str[0]);
      }, $str);

      return $str;
  }
  ```

This is not bulletproof and will fail if for some reason the links in question *should* have  in them for some reason.